# Searching with a dropdown list in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC. I want to use selected items from my dropdownlist to search my database table. The dropdownlist was generated from a BOL model which automatically binds to the view.

Below are my code snippet

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BLL;
using BOL;

namespace DentiCareApp.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class GenerateInvoiceController : Controller
    {
        private TreatmentBs objBs;

        public GenerateInvoiceController()
        {
                objBs = new TreatmentBs();
        }
        // GET: Admin/GenerateInvoice
        public ActionResult Index(string CompanyID)
        {
            DentiCareEntities db = new DentiCareEntities();
            ViewBag.CompanyId = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "CompanyName");

            if (CompanyID == null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return View(db.Treatments.Where(x => x.Company == CompanyID.Take(50)));
            }
            //return View();
        }
```

Also below is the interface of view.

[image]

Secondly, I also want the search result to appear on the same page. How do I do this? If I create a separate action for this, I will need to create a separate view for it. Can partial view be used? If so how?

Below is the code to the View

```
    @model BOL.GenerateInvoice
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <h2>Quickly Generate Invoice</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "GenerateInvoice", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="">
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownList("MyCompany.CompanyId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CompanyId, "Select Company", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyCompany.CompanyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your actual view code? It can be done on one page, but I need to see how your view is handlign this stuff. I assume it takes a model of IEnumerable<Treatments>?

Comment: @br4d.net Okay. Let me add the view here

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like the BOL.GenerateInvoice object the view is expecting is not being passed in by the example controller action so this code wont run when CompanyID is not null. Could you post the GenerateInvoice class? I guess it was generated and is not a proper ViewModel?

Comment: @br4d.net Thanks a bunch. I actually got a clue from your initial post, **I assume it takes a model of IEnumerable<Treatments>?** And since I have a treatment model with a corresponding view, I had to update the treatment view. it's working fine now but I still have to figure out how to update my view based on the company selected. I will update my entire view and model above.

Comment: Awesome! I'll throw some proof of concept code together real quick for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

**Controller action**:

```
public ActionResult Index(string CompanyID)
{
    DentiCareEntities db = new DentiCareEntities();
    ViewBag.CompanyId = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "CompanyName", CompanyID);    // preselect item in selectlist by CompanyID param

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CompanyID))
    {
        return View();
    }

    return View(db.Treatments.Where(x => x.CompanyID == CompanyID).Take(50));
}
```

**View code**:

```
@model IEnumerable<Treatment>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Quickly Generate Invoice</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "GenerateInvoice", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.DropDownList("CompanyId", (SelectList)ViewBag.CompanyId, "Select Company", new { @class = "form-control" })
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
}

@if(Model != null && Model.Any())
{
    foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item)
    }
}
```

You can change the `DisplayFor()` here to show individual properties of the given Treatment, such as `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TreatmentID)` and such

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I implemented what you have but I'm still getting errors on this line 'return View(db.Treatments.Where(x => x.CompanyId == CompanyID).Take(50));' which says: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'

Answer (score 1):

The Above code worked for me but with little tweaks. Here are few modification I made to your code.

1. The parameter in the Index Action was changed from `string` to `integer`.
2. The Optional Parameter in the `ViewBag.CompanyId` was removed.
3. Lastly, the line  `if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CompanyID))` and changed to `if (CompanyID == 0) { return View(treatmentList);}`

The result however is great as it worked like a charm! Thanks for your help!

```
        // GET: Admin/ListTreatment
        public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string sortBy, string Page, int CompanyID = 0)
        {
            ViewBag.sortOrder = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.sortBy = sortBy;

            var treatmentList = objBs.GetALL();

            //ViewBag.employeeCompany = employeeCompany.Distinct();
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "Asc":
                    treatmentList = treatmentList.OrderBy(x => x.TreatmentDate).ToList();
                    break;
                case "Desc":
                    treatmentList = treatmentList.OrderByDescending(x => x.TreatmentDate).ToList();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            ViewBag.CompanyId = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "CompanyName");

            ViewBag.TotalPages = Math.Ceiling(objBs.GetALL().Where(x=>x.CompanyId > 0).Count()/10.0);
            int page = int.Parse(Page == null ? "1" : Page);
            ViewBag.Page = page;

            treatmentList = treatmentList.Skip((page - 1) * 10).Take(10);

            if (CompanyID == 0)
            {
                return View(treatmentList);
            }

            return View(db.Treatments.Where(x => x.CompanyId == CompanyID).Take(50));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

- First : for entity framework id should be nullable, so it can be accepted as argument, the action parameter should be `int? CompanyID`
- Second : the comparison is not correct with `(CompanyID == 0)`

  It should be `(CompanyID == null)`